# ubuntu 13.04 upgrade to 64 bit

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have ubuntu 13.04 dual booting wit MS windows. It is a 32 bit version but the pc is a 64 bit.

When I use the 64 bit install DVD it sees the two main partitions and gives several options but I can't find how to replace the ubuntu 32 with the 64 version without chopping the hard drive into little pieces or formatting the whole drive .

I don't want to to do this and don't recognise any of the partitions shown when  I go to the  "do something else" menu.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to upgrade from a 32bit install to a 64bit install. You'd be able to upgrade to 32bit however.

If you're not recognising the partitions once you are in the livecd you can get information from the installed system to inform your choices.

In your current install open a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+T and run this command

```
mount
```

Check for which partition is mounting as /

Example - partition designations and UUID's are from my system for illustration purposes only.

```
mount
/dev/sda7 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
```

Use that partition in the Something Else option.

At times partition designation can change, you can double check the partition with the UUID.

Run

```
sudo blkid
```

/dev/sda7: LABEL="Tahr" UUID="**ba32749c-2a4e-4e97-bdbc-1d9538490af1**" TYPE="ext4"

In the livecd you can run the `blkid` command again to check the partition designation with the UUID.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is that you've got user documents you don't want to delete, you might check here for information on migrating to a separate `/home` partition:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Once you've migrated to a separate `/home` partition, you can then install the 64-bit version of Ubuntu over the 32-bit version without risking your user documents -- at least, no more so than you would if you were upgrading in place or doing other such activities. (There's always a risk of accidentally clicking the wrong check-box and wiping something out, so keeping a backup is advisable.)

If you've installed lots of custom packages, you can save a list of the packages in your current 32-bit installation:

[How to list all installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages)

This will help you automatically install the matching packages in your 64-bit system, as described in some of the answers and discussions on that page. Of course, you'll need to do this *before* replacing the 32-bit version with the 64-bit version.

You might also want to back up your entire `/etc` directory -- that's where global configuration files live. Having this backup will be handy if you need to re-configure Samba or Apache or something like that.